# Optional components in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I've been writing regex for long time and covering below scenarios by writing two regexes, since I do not know if there's a way to handle it by a single regex. So, I would like to hear if there's a way to write a single regex to capture the both at one shot.

Suppose that we have a standard starting with A and ending with Z, the `field delimiter` is a pipe `|` and each field consist of components delimited by a hat `^`.

- Input1: A|1|1^^3^4^5|loongText|Z
- Input2: A|13|^2^|loongText|Z

The regex should give below output

- Output1 : captured groups 1,,3,4,5
- Output2 : captured groups  ,2,,,

My attempt : `A\|.\d*\|(.*)\^(.*)\^(.*)\^(.*)\^(.*?)\|.+?\|Z` works for the first input but not the second.

What regex matches both inputs and gets the groups in correct order ?

[UPDATE] Group order is important.
So group 1 should be 1, group 2 should be returning an empty and 2 in respectively for input 1 and input 2. Because based on the order they have different meanings in the standard.

- Input3: A|13|1^2^3|loongText|Z
- Expected output: `{"group1" :1, "group2": 2, "group3": 3}`, so having captures in the right group is also important.

Comment: If it were me, I'd extract the third field using a regex, then split it using split instead of trying to do something clever with captured groups.

Comment: Do you need the empty matches? Perhaps like this `(?<=(?:^|\|)(?=\d*\^)[\d^]{0,100})\d+` https://regex101.com/r/mceSCT/1 Or using `\G` with a capture group like `(?:(?:^|\|)(?=\d*\^)|\G(?!\A))\^*(\d+)\d*` https://regex101.com/r/AEbupx/1

Comment: @RealSkeptic this what I'm doing right now already. If the field is not complex split otherwise another regex.

Comment: And how can it become complex? Why another regex? Why aren't you showing us your actual solution?

Comment: @RealSkeptic only having `^` is the simple, and having sub components delimited with different delimiters is complex. i.e. `1^2~2^4#5` here `~` is repetition and # can be another delimiter having different meaning. In such case I'm writing an another regex, but that's not part of this question.

Comment: @MikeM You may answer I've tested your regex at https://regexr.com/. It's almost okay, but for another input `A|13|1^2^3|loongText|Z` it's finding the `3` which supposed to be at position 3 at `group 5`, not as group 3. I've updated the question, let me know if there's still anything not clear to you.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/fTR6qF/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's not matching for Input1 and Input2, but Input3 only. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MikeM Bingo! Please post as answer.

Comment: @MikeM hope you don't mind I answer to it on behalf of you : ) But, even the split function take a regex input. It's inevitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sharing this onbehalf of @MikeM, who answered originaly to this question.

`A\|\d*\|(?:(\d*)\^?)?(?:(\d*)\^?)?(?:(\d*)\^?)?(?:(\d*)\^?)?(?:(\d*))\|.+?\|Z`

This regex matches all 3 inputs in the right group order. Thanks.